# How do I push docker image hosted on ACR to Cloud Foundry?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud-foundry, azure-container-registry, pivotal-web-services

I set up a azure devops pipeline by way of a yml file.  the final step is to create an image and store it in Azure container registry and then push it over to Cloud foundry. Unfortunately I haven't found ACR specific info on the web.

the docker image is already on ACR the problem is just pushing it over to CF. I've copied the commands/ errors below

```
cf push <name>--docker-image <registryname>.azurecr.io/<dockerImageName> --no-manifest --docker-username <myAzureLoginName> //this then prompts me for a password and I enter my azure portal password.
```

```
error: 
 Failed getting docker image manifest by tag: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password
   Staging process failed: Exit trace for group:
   builder exited with error: failed to fetch metadata from [testservicedocker] with tag [latest] and insecure registries [] due to unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password
   Exit status 2
   Staging Failed: STG: Exited with status 2
```

> The cf push documentation says:  The Docker image must contain an
>   /etc/passwd file with an entry for the root user. In addition, the
>   home directory and the shell for that root user must be present in the
>   image file system.

Which mine doesn't but I don't see how that would fix this issue.

Comment: It looks like CF is unable to talk to the Docker registry and get the metadata for your image. It's saying `invalid username/password`, which would refer to `cf push --docker-username` and the password you enter. Double check that entering the correct info. It may also be that the registry requires some alternative type of authentication, like GCR (https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-5/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html#gcr). I'm not sure about Azure, but could be a similar situation.

Comment: Do you try to add the variable `CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD=YOUR-PASSWORD` in the begin of the command?